# How to pass input in the java main class from ReadyAPI/SoupUI

Tags: java, jar, ready-api

I am very new to java. Somehow(with the help of the internet) I created the java program for specific functionality using selenium.

I created everything in the main class and it's working fine. Now I have to create the Jar file for this and use this jar file in the ReadyAPI/SoupUI to call this class (Basically main method) and I do need to pass some values as an input while calling it.

But I am lost here (it might be very silly things to do), Can someone please help to provide some guidance here. It will be really helpful.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, did you tried using command line to run you jar file as you can pass some input from there while starting. for example `java -jar MyApplication.jar "some input"` this "some input" string will be passed to your main method `String[] args` parameter and you can use this array for whatever you want

Comment: Hi @Mustahsan, Thanks for the quick response. I did not execute from the command line, however, I tried with eclipse and it's working fine. What I want to know is when I create a jar file of it and keep in ReadyAPI tool /bin/ext folder, how can I call that jar to run.

Comment: just open terminal/command line in that folder and run the above command i  mentioned

Comment: @Mustahsan, I do not want to execute jar from the command prompt. What I want is to use that jar in Ready API so I have created the jar and copied to readyAPI bin/ext folder. Now how I execute that jar passing arguments from ready api using grovvy script